# Resize Androids Home Softbutton

Tags: android, android-widget, android-gui

I have got the 2.2 android with Home button on screen(soft button), Now  I need to change the size of that button to make wider and taller. Also that is embedded device so I have no app store etc. So how to change the buttons Bigger.

Comment: what is "android 2.2 with Home button on screen(soft button)". Post screenshot or explain more. 2.2 did not use onscreen buttons for the Os

Comment: is there some android screen configuration options?

Comment: This is probably made by a custom rom, I'd suggest you looking for this device on xda-developers for some rom with what you want or if you have root on the device you could replace the app which does the buttons.

Comment: This is not standard feature. check what ROM you are using and look for support on related forums or xda-developers

Comment: Anyway - suggest something please!!! Where would you look in the code first. There is loads of code. Do not know where to start to look.